# Alguém pode me ajudar com a função GET?

Tags: php, mysql, get

To fazendo um site de compras, dai tem a tabela produtos e a tabela de pedidos, onde depois que a pessoa compre algo grava na tabela pedidos, mas queria gravar o id do produto na tabela pedidos, como fazer isso por GET, sendo que ele já pega o id por GET para aparecer no carrinho?

Comment: Você pode disponibilizar o código que está utilizando? Mas para gravação você deverá o método POST.

Comment: Dá pra ajudar sim, basta colocar o código ou a parte dele que tem a dúvida.

Comment: na verdade é que eu não sei fazer isso, então não tem código kkkkk não sei por onde começar, procurei mas não achei muita coisa sobre

Comment: Qual a linguagem você está usando em seu `frontend` para enviar os dados para o banco de dados?

Answer (score 0):

Visite a documentação do PHP:

**[PHP: $_GET - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)**

Quanto a ele já estar pegando o ID por GET, se entendi direito, você pode usar outra variável para passar outros valores, separando-as pelo caractere **&**. O GET recupera valores através da URL da página:

```
http://www.pagina.com.br/index.php?id=1&outra_variavel=valor
```

Ao carregar essa página, para capturar o valor dos parâmetros "id" e "outra_variavel", usa-se:

```
$idProduto = $_GET['id'];
$outroValor = $_GET['outra_variavel'];
```

**OBS.:** Se for tratar dados sensíveis, como senha, utilize o método POST, e se necessário com criptografia (md5, por exemplo).

Não sei se isso ajuda, qual seu nível de conhecimento, ou em que parte está do projeto, então é o que posso fazer no momento. Boa Sorte!